# Sometimes it shows the error #1044

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql

I've just installed Joomla! 3.3 but sometimes, when I want to change a parameter, it shows the next error:

> 1044 Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database
>   '*****' SQL=LOCK TABLES `h2ap7_assets` WRITE

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, turned out to be incorrect user privileges in the **MySQL** database.

You can manage your database users via your web hosting account, cpanel, or phpmyadmin etc.

Manage your database, select user, grant **all** privileges.

Wiki docs are [here](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/user_management)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check if the user you are using has the necessary permissions.

To quote the MySQL manual:

> You must have the LOCK TABLES privilege, and the SELECT privilege for each object to be locked.

If you have access to a MySQL console, you can check it with:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
```

Or you can query the `users` table `mysql.user` and check for the column `Lock_tables_priv: Y`